# Adding the condition that it appends only once

Tags: jquery

Here's my jQuery snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#button").click(function(e) {
    $("body").append('Source:CIA World Factbook');
});


});
```

I want to append only once by clicking on a button,

Here's the source for the button,

```
<div id="button"> Show Sources </div>
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#button").one('click', function(e) {
    $("body").append('Source:CIA World Factbook');
});
```

`.one()` will execute the click event just one time.

Read more about **[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.one()` above just as @thecodeparadox suggested (and I have absolutely no problems about that), and that should work great.

... but if your button has absolutely no use *after clicking it once*, why not consider hiding it instead?

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    // do the reveal
    //
    // then hide this button
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Doesn't seem to be any point in keeping it in the layout. Let other elements take up the space.

#### EDIT

... or removing it even.

```
$(this).remove();
```